# Operator overloading using deep copy in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class String 
{
  char *value;
  int len;

  public:
  String()
  {
    len=0;
    value=0;
  } 
  ~String() {}

  String(char *s)
  {
    len=strlen(s);
    value=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(value,s);

  }
  String(String & s)
  {
    len=s.len;
    value=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(value,s.value);
  }


 friend String operator+(String obj1, String obj2)
  {
    String obj3;
    obj3.len=obj1.len+obj2.len;
    obj3.value=new char [obj3.len+1];

    strcpy(obj3.value,obj1.value);
    strcat(obj3.value,obj2.value);
    return obj3;
    }

   friend  String operator=(String obj1, String obj2)
    {

        String obj3;
        strcpy(obj3.value,obj1.value);
        strcat(obj3.value,obj2.value);
        return obj3;
    } 


  void display()

 { cout<<value<<endl; }

};


  int main()
 {

    String s1("Bodacious ");
    String s2("AllienBrain");
    String s3;
    s3=s1+s2;
    s3.display();

    getch(); 
 }
```

As I am already operated the operator + in my code but i also want to overload the `operator=` to conactenate both the strings but this code shows no error when i overload the + operator but it shows the correct output i.e. Bodacious AllienBrain.

But when i overload the `operator=` it throws error so anyone tell me whats wrong with me?

Comment: `operator =` cannot be a friend function.

Comment: If you've got any error output, you should post it as well.

Comment: @ Yksisarvinen  when i removed the friend tag it still throws errors

Comment: @ Rhathin it shows error during compilation

Comment: and what is that error? Please include it in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @A.kelly then you should be able to easily copy it from compiler console.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate version of overloaded = operator would be as below:

```
class String 
{
///...
String& operator=(const String& obj2)
  {
      if(this->value ){
        delete this->value;  // Free if existing
        this->value = NULL;
      }
      len = obj2.len;
      this->value = new char[len + 1];

      strcpy(this->value, obj2.value);
      return *this;
  }
///
};
```